# Why is my question off topic?

Tags: discussion

[Can I import a gun-shaped console controller‎ from the United States into the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67473/can-i-import-a-gun-shaped-console-controller-from-the-united-states-into-the-uk)

How is it different from

[Can I bring soil samples from Cuba / US to Switzerland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67679/can-i-bring-soil-samples-from-cuba-us-to-switzerland)

[Carrying Condoms while traveling to Dubai](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67617/carrying-condoms-while-traveling-to-dubai)

Answer (score 5):

This question was off-topic because it was fundamentally about (imitation) firearms regulation in the UK, not travel. The answer requires knowledge not just of customs and airport security rules, but of a particular country's criminal law on weapons. While you got some good answers from people who dug into UK law on the topic, this site is not intended to handle every conceivable question of the form "what is the law in Country X about Y?" when Y has little to nothing to do with travel.

To put it another way, this is **travel**.stackexchange, not importexportofgoods.stackexchange. Normal travelers will bring various articles with them as part of their travels, and so questions about customs are not always out of scope, but the primary focus needs to be on travel, not picking a random article and asking if you can import it somewhere.

Condoms and small vials of soil (for the hobby purpose of maintaining a personal collection of the places you've visited) are things a reasonable traveler might want to carry, and those questions pertain more to customs rules than generally applicable law.

I'll add that this isn't a court of law where you can point to other precedent and say "but this question wasn't off-topic so mine shouldn't be either." Your question was put on hold as off-topic because a sufficient number of high reputation users voted to do so, and an insufficient number have voted to reopen it. Other questions are open because that hasn't happened to them.

Comment: I was not planning in anyway to use the argument "this question wasn't off-topic so mine shouldn't be either", I was just ASKING and you answer is just awesome it really helped, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close it because you were trolling, as you stated yourself in [your question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/revisions/67473/1) before it was edited by someone else, quoting you:

> PS: damn trolling, now when I need real advice you'll think I m trolling.

There are other ways to get some rep if that's what you're after, here are some:

- Answer real questions in the site, [some have bounties on them](https://travel.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured), good chance for you to get some rep instead of trolling.
- Ask real questions about travel, if you do not travel, then start travelling, if you can't travel, better save the money you plan to [spend on a toy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67473/can-i-import-a-gun-shaped-console-controller-from-the-united-states-into-the-uk) and travel. If you can't travel due to age restrictions, it's OK. Just wait a few more years and when you are 21 and with the money you saved from NOT buying toys you can travel and then ask real questions on TSE. We will wait for you.
- Find another SE site which is about something you actually do, unlike travelling which you don't do. There's a [LEGO.SE](http://bricks.stackexchange.com), [Gameing.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Fantasy.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) and [many other sites about many different topics](http://stackexchange.com/sites#users). Take a pick, and enjoy your time :)

Finally, do NOT think that I hate you, I do not even know you to hate you, I even myself answered one or two of your questions before I knew you were trolling. Please, stop doing whatever you're doing and ask/answer real stuff.

Comment: I haven't been trolling and I refuse such accusations. The mod who declined my report should be ashamed of himself to allow you to say that.